# How do I add an image to the imagefield in django model that is present in the static folder?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Basically, I have an image file certificate.png in the static folder. I have written a view that will access this image and then write the student's name on it. I now want to add this image to the ImageField 'certificate' in the Model 'My_course'. I am not able to figure out how to do that. Please help.

This is the view:

```
def certificate(request, slug):
course = My_course.objects.get(course=Course.objects.get(slug=slug), user=request.user)
try:
    course.certificate.url
except ValueError:
    image = Image.open('course/static/course/images/Certificate.png')
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    font = ImageFont.truetype('course/static/course/fonts/Oswald-Medium.ttf', size=100)
    (x, y) = (700, 570)
    name = request.user.first_name + ' ' + request.user.last_name
    color = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
    draw.text((x, y), name, fill=color, font=font)
    image.save('course/static/course/images/Certificate'+str(course.id)+'.png')
    certimage = urllib.request.urlretrieve(static('course/images/Certificate'+str(course.id)+'.png'))
    course.certificate.save(os.path.basename(course.url), File(open(certimage[0], 'rb')))
    course.save()
return render(request, 'course/certificate.html', {'image':course.certificate,'msg':'Error did not occur'})
```

This is the model:

```
class My_course(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
payment = models.ForeignKey(Payment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
certificate = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Please do you have template HTML for the view and can you please share it so that i help you !?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is from here:

```
course.certificate.save(os.path.basename(course.url), File(open(certimage[0],'rb')))
```

Instead of **os.path.basename(course.url)** you should insert your file name, right now you are giving the save method a path instead of the file name.

It would be like:

```
from django.core.files import File

local_file = open(f'./APP_NAME/FILE_PATH', "rb")
djangofile = File(local_file)
product.image.save('FILE_NAME.jpg', djangofile)
local_file.close()
```